# Error when trying to add another clause into code

Tags: c++

I'm new to coding and i'm working on an assignment. I created a code to input test scores and read out grades based on the score. I am trying to add a clause that will display "invalid" for scores that are above 100 and below 0 but I cannot find a way to add it without receiving some sort of error in the code. I tried adding another if clause and it works but it prints out invalid for score that would indeed be valid.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     int testScore;

    cout << "Enter test score" << endl;
    cin >> testScore;

    if (testScore >= 90)
        cout << "Your grade is A" << endl;
    else if (testScore >= 80)
        cout << "Your grade is B" << endl;
    else if (testScore >= 70)
        cout << "Your grade is C" << endl;
    else if (testScore >= 60)
        cout << "Your grade is D" << endl;
    else 
        cout << "Your grade is F" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ I believe this would be very useful to you

Comment: Thank you i needed this

Answer (score 3):

You want

`if (testScore > 100 || testScore < 0)`

at the beginning of your if-else-if chain.